# Uninterruptible Query

Tags: mysql, database, concurrency

I want to insert a record to a table and retrieve the inserted record's ID which is set as auto_increment. However, **there is a possibility that between the insertion and retrieve operation, another user intervene by inserting another data** to the table. Which means, I may retrieve the wrong record's ID. How can I avoid this problem in MySQL? Thank you.

The Query I am using is `SELECT CustomerID FROM Customers order by CustomerID desc limit 1;`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add a new column to the `Customers` table and name it `ConnectionID` or `SessionID` . And when inserting a new record make sure to include a unique value for `ConnectionID` which should refer to a unique value that changes every time someone tries to insert a new record (Customer). and when Selecting, use that `ConnectionID` That you generated now and saved it in the last query, use it in a `WHERE` clause to make sure you only get the last record you inserted and avoid any other records inserted meanwhile by other users.

The `Customers` table would be something like this:

```
+------------+----------+----------+-----+----------------+
| CustomerID |  column1 |  column2 | ... |   ConnectionID |
+------------+----------+----------+-----+----------------+
|      1     | value1-1 | value2-1 | ... |  anothervalue  |
+------------+----------+----------+-----+----------------+
|      2     | value1-2 | value2-2 | ... |  UniqueValue   |
+------------+----------+----------+-----+----------------+
|      3     | value1-3 | value2-3 | ... |  UniqueValue   |
+------------+----------+----------+-----+----------------+
|      4     | value1-4 | value2-4 | ... | someothervalue |
+------------+----------+----------+-----+----------------+
```

So the `INSERT` statement would be like this:

```
INSERT INTO Customers (column1, column2, ..., ConnID) VALUES('value1-3', 'value2-3', ..., 'UniqueValue');
```

And the query that will `SELECT` the last auto increment ID inserted by you would be:

```
SELECT CustomerID FROM Customers WHERE ConnID = 'UniqueValue' ORDER BY CustomerID desc limit 1;
```

Comment: The one who are going to insert data in this table are users who are just signing up to the system. Wouldn't using `UserID` be irrelevant?

Comment: Also you can make it by email: a column named `userEmail` or by session id of the current user process .. `userSessionID`

Comment: I prefer the session ID of the current user inserting the customer. Then you can select based on your session id to make sure you get the right record (the last auto increment value). If you agree, I will edit my answer to include that idea.

Comment: Oh, I see, you mean I had to use `connection_id()` right? Got it! Please edit your answer, I'll mark it as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the auto increment value of an inserted row as followed:

```
INSERT INTO Customers (column1,column2,...) VALUES('value1','value2',...);
SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();
```

Comment: What if another user inserted another record a few micro seconds before `SELECT LAST_INSERT_ID();` is called? Wouldn't that be problematic?